# This file has Custom XML elements that are no longer supported in Word. Saving the file will remove these elements permanently

Tags: ms-word

One of my customers has reported seeing the following message when working in documents created from templates that I provided:

> This file has Custom XML elements that are no longer supported in Word. Saving the file will remove these elements permanently.

I understand that this message relates to Custom XML Markup (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/custom-xml-elements-not-supported). I can confirm that there is no Custom XML Markup in the document.

Any idea what could be causing this error to display?

Comment: Not really, as long as the user isn't doing something like include material from a document that *does* have custom XML. Word has been known to corrupt documents by resequencing some bits of XML (and perhaps an out-of-place XML element would trigger that message), but haven't seen that for a long time. Maybe you could provide a debug step that would allow the user to save the content of ActiveDocument.Content.WordOpenXml before their actual save, and inspect the XML.

Comment: Or perhaps an Autocorrect entry that for some reason inserts custom xml. BTW, can the user actually *see* any Custom XML tagging? Also, does this user still use any Smart Tags (not sure if they even work any more). It's conceivable that someone coded a custom smart tag that inserted custom xml.

Comment: It's actually happening to one of my testers. They're just creating documents from my template and getting this message before they've pasted any content in.. I'm confident that there is no XML tagging in the template.

Comment: Can you put a copy of the template for download somewhere? Or is it confidential? Assume you have already ruled out the possibility that any other startup code is causing the problem.